# Login loop on ubuntu 14.04. Other user can log in. Checked Xauthority, and ~/.profile.

Tags: login, lightdm

When logging in to ubuntu 14.04 I am encountering a login loop on my main account. Upon entering my password, the login box disappears to leave the wallpaper displaying alone. Then after maybe 1-2 minutes, the screen becomes black for a moment before returning to the login. I can still reach and log in to tty.

This is after weeks of grapics related issues that cropped up when I tried to change the nvidia graphics drivers, which resulted in a sporadic hanging on the splash screen on boot-up. This may be unrelated, but I feel it may be a compounding factor.

**Notes:**

- I created a second, non-admin user, which can login fine and reach a working Unity session.
- My main user account (se14) seems to have permissions for ~/.Xauthority and ~/.ICEauthority:

  ```
  se14@cdt001-lap:~$ ls -ld ~/.*authority
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 se14 se14 55110 Jul 20 15:07 /home/se14/.ICEauthority
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 se14 se14    55 Jul 20 15:07 /home/se14/.Xauthority
  ```
- I have tried to switch to gdm via:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
  ```

  but after choosing gdm when prompted this just gives a black screen with an underscore top-left when I reboot. I then have to go back into tty2 to switch to lightdm and reboot again.
- I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling gdm, lightdm, xorg and even ubuntu-desktop.
- My ~/.profile file was the default file. Still, I deleted it and rebooted axccording to advice I had seen in other threads. Nothing.

If anyone knows of anything more I can do, I'd greatly appreciate the effort. I'm not so great at ubuntu either, so specific commands in any answers would be hugely helpful.

Many Thanks